# Make an announcement type thing to notify new users with 0% acceptance rate

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users, accept-rate

I've noticed quite a few people recently with a 0% acceptance rate. (and more than I'd seen in the past).

I'm not sure what could be causing this, but I think one thing may help to steer these new users in the right direction is an announcement/update put to them when their acceptance rate is 0%.

By announcement I mean how it will alert you when you get new badges and such. I had something in mind like

> You have a 0% acceptance rate. You
>   should **learn more about how to
>   accept answers** and **how the site
>   works**

(where bold is relevant links)

Comment: I also hate it when people get frustrated with beginners with a 0% acceptance rate and tell them to up it, without giving any useful information. "0% accept rate" sounds very alien to a beginner. I always link to [the faq entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).